# Why window.onload works in body and not in head tag in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have tried to call the function using window.onload but it works only when I place it body tag as below but when I place it in the head tag (commented out) it doesn't work though the function gets called (I have put an alert and checked.)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html5>
    <html>
    <head>
         <script>
             function onl()
             {          
                var x=document.forms[0].elements[0].name;
                document.write(x);
            }
            //window.onload = onl();
         </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name=usern>
            <input type = "text" name ="username">
            <input type = "password" name ="password">
            <input type ="submit" name="sybmitb">
        </form>
        <script>
                 window.onload = onl();
        </script>
        <div id = "txt">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The DOM needs to rendered first, before `onl()` function can be of any use since it relies on the form to actually exist first. Btw, proper syntax is: `window,onload.onl;` no parenthesis in this case. If you have parenthesis, that'll be interpreted by the JS engine that you are calling that function as soon as possible. The reason why that's not great in this case is because letting the function get called at the browser's discretion will result in better loading sequence. As a general rule, I always place my `<script>` block before the closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: Sorry I am new to javascript and don't understand few basic things so isn't the onload property is to make sure that window is loaded and DOM is created for all the elements ?

Comment: Just read the answers you got already, they have references. :-)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't run in the head because the brackets used after the assignment cause the function to immediately be run. That mean it causes an error because the document hasn't loaded yet and so causes the form elements to be undefined.

In the head, if you change

```
window.onload = onl();
```

to

```
window.onload = onl;
```

Then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You must pass the handler function to `document.load` (or `window.load`), not the return of your function. So use `document.onload = onl;` instead of `document.onload = onl();` (see more here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload)

So in result :

```
<!DOCTYPE html5>
    <html>
    <head>
         <script>
             function onl()
             {          
                var x=document.forms[0].elements[0].name;
                document.write(x);
            }
            document.onload = onl;
         </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name=usern>
            <input type = "text" name ="username">
            <input type = "password" name ="password">
            <input type ="submit" name="sybmitb">
        </form>
        <div id = "txt">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Regards,
Julien Q.

Edit : Sorry I misread before ;)

Answer (score 0):

When you assign a function like that, you need to be sure not to invoke it. When you put parentheses on the end of a function name, it will be invoked immediately even if it's being assigned to something like the window's load event.

So, you simply have to replace `onl()` with `onl`:

```
window.onload = onl;
```

As for why it works in the body, it's because the document has pretty much finished loading when it gets to the end of the body.

Assigning `onl()` to the window's onload property isn't erroneous because you're assigning the return value of `onl()`, which is `undefined`, to window.onload.

Also, I'd recommend not using `window.onload` but `document.onload`, because `document.onload` is fired when the DOM is ready, not when the files requested are ready.